# How to make NSMenu drop down periodically without user input

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have created a statusbar menu item on the top of my window like this:

```
- (void)createStatusBarItem {
    _statusBar = [NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];
    _statusItem = [_statusBar statusItemWithLength:NSSquareStatusItemLength];
    _statusItem.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"icon_off.png" ];
    _statusItem.highlightMode = YES;
    _statusItem.menu = [self createStatusBarMenu];
}
```

with the menu:

```
- (NSMenu *)createStatusBarMenu {
    NSMenu *menu = [[NSMenu alloc] init];
    ...
}
```

I am now wanting to periodically make the menu drop down as if a user had clicked on the status bar icon. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed. First create a repeating NSTimer to call a method repeatedly and store it as a property (so you can invalidate it later, etc.)

```
self.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval: 5.0 target: self selector: @selector(displayMenu:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer: self.timer forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Then in the method it calls, display the menu.

```
[self.statusItem popUpStatusItemMenu: self.statusItem.menu];
```

In this case it'll pop up every 5 seconds or so. However since you don't know when it closes, the user could close it and then have the timer call and reopen it a second later. So you might want to set yourself as the menu's delegate and implement `menuWillOpen:` and `menuDidClose:`. In `menuDidClose:` you'd probably remake the timer (or set it's fire date) in order to reset the interval so that it'll wait another 5 seconds before opening the menu from the time the menu last closed. You could also create a timer to close the menu automatically if the user didn't close it by themselves in `menuWillOpen:`, etcetera, so that the menu opens every X seconds and closes after X seconds by itself if nothing is done with it (you'd call the NSMenu's `cancelTracking` for that.)